# Преследование врага

Tags: c#, unity3d

В моих планах - кликнуть пкм на врага, чтобы персонаж подбежал к врагу и, когда игрок к нему уже будет подбегать, чтобы бежал не к его прошлому местоположению и пробегал сквозь него (Враг при опр. расстоянии начинает идти на перса), а именно к врагу. Пока у меня получилось, как не нужно было бы(Он бежит на его прежнее местоположение).:

void Update () {

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                target = hit.transform;
                transform.LookAt(target);
                tPosition = hit.point;
                GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().SetDestination(tPosition);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, сохраните компонент `NavMeshAgent` вашего персонажа в методе `Start()` в отдельную переменную, чтобы не выполнять в каждом `Update()` метод `GetComponent<>`, так как он довольно дорогостоящий.

Например:

```
NavMeshAgent navAgent;

void Start(){
// это называется кэшированием компонента
navAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}
```

Во-вторых, модифицируйте ваш код таким образом, чтобы если вы кликнули на врага, его компонент `transform` сохранялся в отдельную переменную, например `Transform enemyTransoform`.
Далее добавьте следующий код в метод `Update()`, перед обработкой клика :

```
if (enemyTransoform != null)
{
  transform.LookAt(target);
  navAgent.SetDestination(tPosition);
}
```

Таким образом вы будете в каждом `Update()` корректировать путь вашего персонажа.
Также, чтобы ваш персонаж не проходил сквозь врага, можно добавить вычисление расстояния до противника и сравнивать его с некой удобной вам констаной, например радиусом NavMeshAgent вашего персонажа. Если расстояние будет меньше, чем этот радиус останавливайте персонажа и выполняйте другие действия (например атака или что бы вы не захотели).